# ¿Como enviar datos de un formulario mendiante DataTable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando una función para poder obtener los datos de la tabla usando un formulario donde se encuentra dos input tipo date para poder hacer una búsqueda mediante un intervalo de fechas .
este es formulario :

```html
<div class="row">
  <form id="tablebuscar" method="post">
    <div class="input-daterange">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="date" name="fechainicio" id="fechainicio" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="date" name="fechafinal" id="fechafinal" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
      <input type="button" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

esta es la funcion :

```js
// #tablebuscar   - es el id del formulario
// #table   - es el id dela tabla 
// #buscar   - es el id del boton que hace llamado a la funcion 

$("#tablebuscar").on('click', '#buscar', function() {
  // al hacer click en el boton obtengo las dos fechas del formulario
  var data = $("#tablebuscar").serialize();
  // luego "destruyo" la tabla anterior para inicializar nuevamente con la respuesta de los datos enviados
  $("#table").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  lista(data); // luego llamo a la funcion
})

///  
function lista(data) {
  table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "240px",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, -1],
      [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, "Todo"]
    ],
    "scrollCollapse": false,
    "processing": true, 
    "serverSide": true, 
    "order": [], 
    "language": {
      "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
      "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados en su busqueda",
      "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registros",
      "info": "Mostrando  de _START_ al _END_  de  _TOTAL_ registros",
      "infoEmpty": "No existen registros",
      "infoFiltered": "",
      "search": "Buscar:",
      "processing": "Procesando...:",
      "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Último",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
      },
    },
 
    "ajax": {
      "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>historial_planilla/ajax_list",
      "type": "POST",
      "data": data // <- DATA contiene las dos fechas que                          envio a la funcion ajax_list 
    },
  
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [-1], 
      "orderable": false,
    }, ],
  });
}
```

```js
//Este es el codigo del CONTROLADOR :
function ajax_list() {
  //Aqui estoy recibiendo los valores de los input 

  $fechainicio = $this - > input - > post("fechainicio");
  $fechafinal = $this - > input - > post("fechafinal");
  //y ago una condicion si esque esta vacios poner un valor por defecto

  if ($fechainicio == "") {
    $fechainicio = "01/01/1900";
  } else {
    $fechainicio = $this - > input - > post("fechainicio");
  }

  if ($fechafinal == "") {
    $fechafinal = "31/12/2300";
  } else {
    $fechafinal = $this - > input - > post("fechafinal");
  }

//y los imprimo
echo $fechainicio;
echo $fechafinal;

}
//Ahora el problema esque siempre me imprime el valor por defecto como si nunca ubiera enviado los valores de los input , alguien sabe porque pasa esto?
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

No se si realmente esta enviando correctamente los datos del formulario 
ya que cuando pongo echo  en las variables siempre me trae el valor por defecto como si nunca se hubiese enviado los  datos.

Comment: buenos dias, la mejor forma de filtrar los datos con dos fecha es realizar una consulta sql utilizando la función BETWEEN en la consulta ya sea por medio de ajax, además la librería datatables no tiene esa función

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude pasar las variables

En la funcion le paso dos variables inicio y final

```js
function lista(inicio,final){
  table = $('#table').DataTable({
//  Codigo datatable

        "ajax": {
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>historial_planilla/ajax_list",
          type: "POST",
           data:{
             inicio:inicio, final:final //<!-----
            }

        },

   
        });
}
```

y en el controlador

```html
function ajax_list() {
  //Aqui estoy recibiendo los valores de los input 
        $inicio;
        $final;

        if ($_POST["inicio"] != "") {

            $inicio = $_POST["inicio"];
        } else {
            $inicio = "1900-01-01";
        }

        if ($_POST["final"] != "") {

            $final = $_POST["final"];
        } else {
            $final = "2300-31-12";
        }

//y los imprimo
echo $inicio;
echo $final;

}
```